# mongoDB | Mongorestore inside spawn or exec

Tags: mongodb, exec, spawn, mongorestore

i am trying to initiate a mongo restore, inside of an `exec` but i get a buffer overflow
if doing it with `spawn` getting that `|[0m /bin/sh: 1: --nsFrom: not found`

any ideas?